# How to display time format using angular2-moment

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-moment

**.html**

```
{{2018-02-26T12:00:14.151Z | amParse : 'YYYY/MM/DD' | amDateFormat : 'LL'}}
```

The above above gives the result as `February 26, 2018` but I need the result as 
`FEBRUARY 2018` .

I am using anular2-moment module [link here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-moment) I have to use this module only.

Answer (score 1):

Angular 2 comes built in with several custom pipes including the UpperCasePipe. To get to the result you want:

```
{{2018-02-26T12:00:14.151Z | amParse : 'YYYY/MM/DD' | amDateFormat : 'MMMM YYYY' | uppercase}}
```

Note that the amDateFormat is based on the format in momentjs docs: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

The final step is piping the string to UpperCasePipe using '| uppercase':
https://angular.io/api/common/UpperCasePipe

Comment: Thanks...it soved my issue